# ¿Cómo imprimo las filas en las que una columna tiene un valor específico?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Desde un archivo se obtiene información de las líneas que empatan con una búsqueda y se guardan en una variable.

**Ejemplo:**

```
valores=awk -F ":" '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}' archivo | grep "201025" -n | cut -d ":" -f1
```

---

Luego haces una iteración por la variable y después buscas línea en especifico en el archivo.

**Ejemplo:**

```
for valor in $valores; do
    sed -n "${valor}p" archivo
done
```

Pero esto manda un error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `

¿Alguien puede explicarme a que se debe y como se podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Intuyo que estás utilizando programas demás. Por ejemplo, en tu código de `awk`, podrías hacer `$ awk -F : '/201025/' archivo` y obtienes toda la línea que coincida con esa cadena. Así te evitas usar sed, y grep. Incluso podría quitarle el parámetro `-F` ya que no lo usas para algo no trivial.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu comentario. Permiteme poner un ejemplo de lo que quiero filtrar Linea1 "8118:001:201010:000504:1294:001:H:900:0801" Linea2 "8118:001:051110:201010:1294:001:H:900:0801" en este caso la cuarta columna puede llegar a tener el mismo valor de la columna tres. si hago hago un grep por el valor que me interesa "201010" de la tercer columna me devolveria tambien la segunda linea. Por eso es que mi lógica si lo parto en 3 columnas y hago el grep, obtengo el numero de la linea de la coincidencia y regreso al archivo y solo le pido me regrese esa o esas lineas ya no hay prob

Comment: Eso deberías ponerlo en tu publicación para que más personas pudieran dar sus soluciones. Por otro lado, tal vez en tu código tengas un error tipográfico por usar la variable "valororoes" en lugar de "valores". Aunque también porque parece que no usas adecuadamente un *command substitution*, es decir, asignar tu variable de la forma `valores=$(<lista de comandos>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a las aclaraciónes que se han hecho en los comentarios, puedo suponer un archivo como este:

```
8118:001:201010:000504:1294:001:H:900:0801
8118:001:051110:201010:1294:001:H:900:0801
```

En el cual se desea obtener el renglón en el que el tercer campo, separado por el caracter ":", coincida con un patrón.

Suponiendo que este patrón es el número "201010", entonces se debería obtener únicamente el primer renglón.

Awk es un buen aliado en estos casos:

```
$ awk -F : '$3 == 201010' archivo
8118:001:201010:000504:1294:001:H:900:0801
```

Gracias a que `awk` sigue una sencilla y poderosa idea de ver todo como `patrón{acción}`, y **donde la acción por defecto es imprimir todo el renglón**.

Entonces, en este pequeño script, lo único que hago es comparar el tercer campo (dado por el token `$3`) con el resultado esperado; después, al no poner una acción, se ejecuta la que está por defecto.

Comment: cuando ejecuto tu solucion lo que hace es remplazar todos esos datos de la columna tres por el 201010 no realiza una busqueda.

Comment: Listo, para que ejecute tu script como busqueda se requiere doble signo de igual. Gracias por tu solucion. Sin embargo, mi script no tiene error tipografico, cuando ingreso los numeros de linea manualmente, mi script lo toma sin problema pero cuando los toma por la busqueda planteada manda ese error. Tendras alguna idea de que sera y como podria solucionarlo.

Comment: ¡Gracias por hacerlo notar!, fue un error tipográfico. En mi terminal lo tengo justo como explicas. En un segundo lo corrijo.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien  a qué te refieres con "manualmente" o "por la búsqueda planteada". Creí que la búsqueda planteada lo daba mi respuesta con `awk`.